# Why doesn't document.cookie show all the cookie for the site?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I go to a forum which uses vBulletin 3.8. When I log in, I use firebug to see what cookies were set. I see these cookies:

> __utmb, __utmc, __utma, __utmz, bbsessionhash, vbseo_loggedin, bbpassword, bbuserid, bblastactivity, bblastvisit

They all had a value set, and the domain was identical.

But when I use JavaScript to view them, it only saw these cookies:

> __utmb, __utmc, __utma, __utmz, vbseo_loggedin,  bblastactivity, bblastvisit

In firebug, I only see these three cookies: bbsessionhash, bbpasword and bbuserid, that were actually set. HTTPOnly in column HTTPOnly. What does it mean and is that the reason I can't see those cookies in JavaScript using `document.cookie`?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

From [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Cookie_theft):

> Cookies are not directly visible to
> client-side programs such as
> JavaScript if they have been sent with
> the HttpOnly flag. From the point of
> view of the server, the only
> difference with respect of the normal
> case is that the set-cookie header
> line is added a new field containing
> the string `HttpOnly':
>
> `Set-Cookie: RMID=732423sdfs73242; expires=Fri, 31-Dec-2010 23:59:59 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.net; HttpOnly`
>
> When the browser receives such a
> cookie, it is supposed to use it as
> usual in the following HTTP exchanges,
> but not to make it visible to
> client-side scripts.
> <s>The `HttpOnly` flag is not part of any standard, and is not implemented in all browsers.</s>

*Update from 2017:* a lot of time had passed since 2009, and `HttpOnly` header flag is became a standard, defined in the [section 5.2.6 of RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.6), with the storage semantics described in the same document (look for "http-only-flag" throughout the RFC text).

There is **no** way to access anything about the `HttpOnly` cookies from "non-HTTP" APIs, e.g. JavaScript. By design, neither reading, nor writing such cookies is possible.

Comment: But is there a way to access those cookies somehow from the frontend? Cookie manager Chrome extension is showing them, but document.cookie not.

Comment: @SilverRingvee, sorry but there is none. If there is a way, it is a browser security bug (and a quite severe one) that should be reported and fixed.Browser extensions are different matters, though - they have higher privileges than website, and have access to the priliveged APIs (e.g. [`chrome.cookies.getAll` for Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#method-getAll)) that can see all the cookies.

Comment: @SilverRingvee , have you found any way to access the cookies with HTTPOnly flag?

Comment: @RewanthCool and I have now realized that it would be a horribly bad security issue if it was possible.

Comment: @SilverRingvee I tried using a XMLHTTPRequest but no use. Here is the reference: https://forums.asp.net/t/1697306.aspx?It+possiible+to+read+cookies+in+JS+with+httpOnly+flag . Check this out !!

Comment: So what would be the way to delete an HTTPOnly cookie?

Comment: @neiya - Normally an HTTPOnly cookie would be set by the webserver (not sure if JavaScript _can_ set one?) (i.e. in the HTTP response returned by the webserver), and it would need to be cleared by the server too.