# Relationship between the Rails cookie object, the Cookie HTTP header, and document.cookie

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

When I access `document.cookie` in Javascript, it spits out, say:

```
'user_credentials=5beea8874f2db9feb873828'
```

Basically, what appears to be some encoded information. Fine.

When I look at the headers, I do see that exact same string being set to `user_credentials`, but there's also another value being set for `_myapplication_session=BAh7CiIQX`. Unlike with `user_credentials`, this one includes capital letters and letters after F.

So:

- What is `_myapplication_session`? Is this related to the session object in Rails?
- Why doesn't `_myapplication_session` show up with Javascript `document.cookie`?

Comment: `user_credentials` apparently is a string containing hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: I'm perfectly willing to accept that the data contained within is some base 64 representation of some encrypted information that is decoded server-side. I'm asking about its relationship to `document.cookie`&mdash;namely, why it doesn't show up. I'm also asking about its relationship to the Rails-side `cookie` and `session` objects.

Answer (score 6):

> What is _myapplication_session? Is
>   this related to the session object in
>   Rails?

Yes, this is the way Rails identifies user sessions.

> Why doesn't _myapplication_session
>   show up with Javascript
>   document.cookie?

I believe Rails sets `httponly=>true` on session cookies, which means they are (generally) not accessible using client-side scripts, as described in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022112/why-document-cookie-hasnt-show-all-the-cookie-in-the-site).