# Accessing current_user variable from application.js in Rails 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I wish to access my current_user variable from my application.js (I renamed my application.js to application.js.erb so the server could understand my ruby code), so i got something like:

```
function hello(){ alert("<%= current_user.name %>"); }
```

But it fails:

[image]

How can i get session variables like the current_user from devise gem working from a script located in /assets/my_script.js.erb, i think it should not be abled because theese variables might not be accesisible from public sites, or what should do about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Simplest way to use ruby in js files is to use `js.erb` extension to your js file.

Comment: @RAJ agreed, but the problem in this moment is accessing the current_user variable

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Application.js is not evaluated in the context of any session variables or methods. The simplest way to access username from javascript would be to set a cookie in a before_action on application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_user

  private

  def set_user
    cookies[:username] = current_user.name || 'guest'
  end
end
```

Then from any js in app/assets you can access the cookie:

```
alert(document.cookie);
```

A more verbose but arguably cleaner method would be to create a route that accesses the current user and returns the username e.g.

routes.rb

```
get 'current_user' => "users#current_user"
```

users_controller.rb

```
def current_user
    render json: {name: current_user.name}
end
```

application.js

```
$.get('/current_user', function(result){
  alert(result.name);
});
```

Comment: David, could you take a look at this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323316/fullcalendar-passing-js-vars-to-rails-and-vice-versa? It's a similar problem, but I'm not sure what's the best way to handle this one. I think you could tell me the perfect solution in no time. Thanks!

Comment: This works great in dev, but once I pushed to production it doesn't even recognize the script. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @gwalshington is your script in application.js or a custom script? If you've put it elsewhere you'll need to check that you're precompiling your assets correctly - there's lots of questions on SO about this topic

Comment: @DavidJohnSmith it is in app.js

Comment: @DavidJohnSmith Thanks for the response, i really like your approach, i dont get ruby variables to get rendered in the js, but i can fetch them anyway via js or session variable via cookie, Awesome!

Comment: This is a bad idea (to use cookies) because you usually use **signed** cookies - not plain ones like here (for security reasons). And how would you read the signed cookies in your JS file?

Comment: @prograils signing cookies would generally be for when the server expects to read something back out of the cookie at the next request (ie session). In this case all we're doing is sending some data for the client to display so signing is not really necessary. However, there are some obvious drawbacks to the cookie approach, was just trying to demonstrate a quick and dirty approach vs a more robust design.

Answer (score 3):

1. Take a look at [this episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast) in rails casts
2. Try using the [gon gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon)

Comment: I see, i can get my js.erb to understand ruby code, for example alert("<%= 'hi' %> "); works, but i cant get it to work with current_user variable

Answer (score 1):

Pass current user to view as JSON from application controller so that it is available to javascript.

*application controller*:

```
def method_name
  respond_to do |format|
     format.json{ render :json => @user.to_json }
  end
end
```

Comment: This would have the side-effect of exposing all of the user's information to the user, which you might not want to do.