# Can't read cookie when there is cookie in header

Tags: javascript, express

Please refer to the following picture. 
[image]

Front-end code calls back-end api to login a user. Back-end is done using Expressjs 4 and cookie store uses redis.

What confuses me is after login is successful, I can see there is cookie set by expressjs using Chrome Inspector, but

```
document.cookie
```

Shows nothing. You can use "document.cookie" to set and read cookie of your own, which works fine. But I can't read the one set by back-end API as shown in the above screen picture.

**Question**

How to read cookie set by back-end API? or What did I miss here?

Comment: Is it http only?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022112/why-doesnt-document-cookie-show-all-the-cookie-for-the-site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refering to [this documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#cookiehttponly):

> **cookie.httpOnly**
>
> Specifies the boolean value for the `HttpOnly Set-Cookie` attribute. When truthy, the `HttpOnly` attribute is set, otherwise it is not. **By default, the `HttpOnly` attribute is set.**

And according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Secure_and_HttpOnly_cookies):

> HttpOnly cookies aren't accessible via JavaScript through the `Document.cookie` property.

In the devtools, there's a column `HTTP` that will contain a checkmark for that particular cookie, to reflect its `HttpOnly` status.