# Cookie not being recognized after request is returned

Tags: javascript, cookies, vuejs2, laravel-5.4, axios

I have a request being sent to the server which returns a cookie with the response. As I understand it, the cookie should be handled by the browser automatically (at least with AXIOS)? It seems that it is being stored to some capacity, but for some reason `document.cookie` does not output it.

Here is what manages the cookie-related routing:

```
function requirePasscode (to, from, next) {
    console.log(document.cookie);
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('passcode_cookie') > -1) {
        console.log('This should be working');
        next(true);
    } else {
        next ({
            path: '/authenticate/' + to.params.id,
            query: {
                redirect: to.fullPath
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Here is the code that sends the request:

```
    authenticateUser: function() {
        var data = {
            'id' : this.$route.params.id,
            'passcode' : this.state.password,
        };

        var that = this;

        axios.post('/api/authenticate', data).then(function(response) {
            swal('Great!', 'You have been authenticated.', 'success');
            that.$router.push('/test/' + that.$route.params.id);
        }, function(error) {
            swal('Woah!', 'Wrong password, go away.', 'error');
        });
    }
```

Here is the request as seen in chrome dev tools:

```
POST /api/authenticate HTTP/1.1
Host: testing.dev
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 28
Origin: http://testing.dev
X-XSRF-TOKEN: eyJpdiI6IjQxNzZwTkJwOSt1aHJFN1hXWUxXQkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidStZQTlWSlRhYThIXC9YYjFwK1E0bGROaEI3cVRLVGdGTW5YSkxwc0thdk8wYythOUpFRWhseFBpbEV2RU1lZWpQbm4xeUU2RGh5ckhpK1RwUE9nQmhnPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI0NThjZmJkOWJlY2ZhN2M4OGUwNzVlYTIyYzFmMDQxN2VlNDU5NGVmMmUwODFhOTMzMzMyNjE4MzIyNTI4OWY5In0=
X-CSRF-TOKEN: zjafXGptCKWSwHCVFBydBgTL63HnngVRCqLgRLXY
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://testing.dev/authenticate/1?redirect=%2Ftest%2F1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: laravel_token=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%3D; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjQxNzZwTkJwOSt1aHJFN1hXWUxXQkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidStZQTlWSlRhYThIXC9YYjFwK1E0bGROaEI3cVRLVGdGTW5YSkxwc0thdk8wYythOUpFRWhseFBpbEV2RU1lZWpQbm4xeUU2RGh5ckhpK1RwUE9nQmhnPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI0NThjZmJkOWJlY2ZhN2M4OGUwNzVlYTIyYzFmMDQxN2VlNDU5NGVmMmUwODFhOTMzMzMyNjE4MzIyNTI4OWY5In0%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IllSTkY5b0NGb0YwWFcyZGYwenJPaXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiUEx5Nm9XRmY5SXArMkY2REFZbDBkdmppd1FZaVVqWGhoc3loblhRYVY2dGg2Q1RKTnIwdU1MZ25WZnlDRWVvNVIzeVdzOFdUcEJSeTk3c0xCbUwrTlE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjEwMzRkMmYyOGZhZjg5ZGIwMmZlNmY4OTBjMWI2MGVlMWE3OTdhMjRhMGNjNWRkNTBiNWYzNDc2MmMyZmE5MTIifQ%3D%3D
```

Here is the response returned:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 18 Jul 2017 18:08:35 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2k PHP/7.1.5
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.5
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Set-Cookie: passcode_cookie=1337; expires=Tue, 18-Jul-2017 19:48:35 GMT; Max-Age=6000; path=/; HttpOnly
Content-Length: 7
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

It appears that the cookie is being stored:
[image]

However, the `console.log(document.cookie)` returns the following:

```
XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InlvYk9RMkJ4c21zWmtoZ29PMlloNXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiM1VjSDhnRU5PR284cmF0RTNqWEVSY3pcL3R5VFBFNW5GYkljOXVKUG5IMnh1aTM3R0ord2lSeHdLTEVxWndKZVIxeGppcERVSFVzUVwvY3RZQ1J5Zm4zUT09IiwibWFjIjoiYTRlMzc1NjJiMDhmNGEzOGZjYzE4NzkwYjY3ZmUwZjBlMWQwNjZiNGJmZWY3YTUwYzI3MTVkZDcxY2QyYWNjOSJ9
```

Seems like the XSRF token is the only thing being returned. Any ideas on why this may be happening?

Comment: try setting the `withCredentials` config option to `true`. https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#request-config

Comment: Looks like that still didn't do it :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took a while to figure out, but the problem lies in the way Laravel 5 makes the cookie. It seems that `http_only` is enabled by default.

This [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022112/why-doesnt-document-cookie-show-all-the-cookie-for-the-site) describes the problem and offers some solutions.